# ChangingCode From MySQL To PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have made a CMS Script written using MySQL Syntax.

I want to replace the MySQL Syntax with the PDO Syntax. Can someone **help me do it** and **explain to me how to do it**?

This is the code from the script.

```
<?php
    $querytemp = mysql_query("select * from main_setting") or die (mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($querytemp);

    include "inc/upcenter_block.php";

    echo "
        <div class='headmenu'>$row->news1</div>
        <div class='bodymenu'>
        <p>".nl2br($row->news)."</p>
    </div> ";

    include "inc/downcenter_block.php";
?>
```

Comment: Probably, self learning is needed here: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Quite a strange bounty.

Comment: The question is: why?

Comment: For the record to whoever read this: the OP here was sock puppet of [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2572853/user2572853) who was trying to game the system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First if you want to change from `mysql_*` to `PDO`

you will need to change all of your codes in the script,  not only a
       single one that just wont work

and if you going to change the codes from mysql_* to PDO

you will have to change the connection to the database by using PDO

here`s a sample for that :

```
// here we set the variables 
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "testcreate";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "mysql";

// here we are using ( try {} ) to catch the errors that will shows up and handle it in a nicer way
    try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf-8', ''.$dbuser.'', ''.$dbpass.'');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error : <br>' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

---

```
// here we set the varible for the connection = then starting the cennction with new POD();
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf-8', ''.$dbuser.'', ''.$dbpass.'');
```

---

```
// here we set an Attribute to handle the errors
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// you dont need to use it in our case because we already catching the error and handling it in out way
```

---

```
  // here we catch the error then handling it by echo a msg and then we used
  // $e->getMessage(); to get the error msg that should be throwing in the page
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error : <br>' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

### --------------------------------------------

now that we done with the connect
i will show you how to query and fetch tables

```
 // this is how we will use query
 $qr = $db->query()

 // and this is how to fetch it by taking the query variable and use the arrow then fetch 
 $ro = $qr->fetch()
```

iwill show you an example for your code

```
$querytemp = mysql_query("select * from main_setting") or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($querytemp);
```

we will change this to

```
$querytemp = $db->query("select * from main_setting");
$row = $querytemp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

so now you may use `$row->news` with PDO

and now you can change your codes to PDO easily

Answer (score 3):

Converting that script would be something along the line of:

```
// $pdo = connection

try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from main_setting");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    // something went wrong
}

// ...
```

Here's the explanation:

- [`PDO::prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) will create a prepared statement out of a MYSQL query and store it into a variable.
- [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) will execute the prepared statement using the array of parameters passed to it (in this case none because the query does not have any parameter).
- [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) will fetch the results of the last execution. By default it fetches into an array. If you pass `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` it will fetch into an object.

[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) by default [uses exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) which means you can use a try-catch block to catch error (of exception type of `PDOException`).

Also note that:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from main_setting");
$stmt->execute();
```

can be shortened, using [`PDO::query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php), to:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("select * from main_setting");
```

Comment: Explain to me what you did !!

Comment: and now i simply can use $row->news1 to echo out the info from the tabke ?

Comment: @JhonSmith, if your `main_setting` table have a row called `news1`, yes.