# From MYSQL to PDO Best Way

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

as suggested here im converting from mysql to PDO. I'm just learning everything but know enough to be dangerous. Below is some snippets of code i have and looking for the best practice to go from mysql > PDO.

```
function db_query($sql){
global $config;
if($config['debug']){
    echo $sql."\n";
}
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(($config['debug'] || true) && ($myerr = mysql_error())){
    echo $myerr;
}
$rows = array();
if(!$result){ return $rows; }
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
@mysql_free_result($result);
return $rows; }


function get_p4p($where='1=1'){
return db_query ("SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE $where  ORDER BY `rec_order` "  );}
```

I've successfully converted a lot over but for some reason this is troubling me. It might seem elementary to some here and that what im hoping for.. Thanks.

Comment: wow your code is scaring me, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460857/changingcode-from-mysql-to-pdo?rq=1

Comment: it was built in 2006 and never upgraded. im upgrading it all now. Don't worry its not production code.

Comment: If you're upgrading it now, don't post the code expecting people to do it for you, post what you have done or tried and what your issues are if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion there is no easy and clean way to migrate from procedural MySQL to PDO.

PDO provides new awesome features like prepared statements, which require a separation between  query and the data you want to insert into the query (e.g. the id you are searching for). You do not have this separation in your current code, so you cannot update your functions easily to make use of these new features.
Your SQL is most likely also far away from standard SQL. I do not see clear advantages for you to migrate to PDO as you cannot switch to another type of database (like postgresql) anyway. Your only benefit would be that your code does not use obsolete functions anymore.
Further PDO only provides an object-oriented interface. No procedural functions like you currently use. This makes migrating really annoying.

A migration to PDO in my opinion does not make much sense for existing procedural projects. This migration costs lots of effort, knowledge and testing, which you most likely do not want to make for such an old project.

Have you considered migrating from MySQL extension to the new MySQL**i** extension instead?
MySQLi provides both, a object-oriented and a procedural interface. Thus the changes in the interfaces are much less. (Basically all procedural functions now require a connection as first parameter.)
MySQLi does provide new features too (like prepared statements). You can use them if you want to. But you do not have to.
In sum this makes migration a lot easier. If you provide the connection as the first parameter to all the functions which require it, this might be all you have to change.

MySQLi would be the way I would go.

Comment: this is not a real project but more of a learning tool in my local host. thanks for the feedback... i think i might have figured it out. Its a really really small application.